# How to calculate precision / recall score for keywords in sklearn / Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, precision-recall

I have the following code that calculates precision/recall and F1 score for my model, which detects keywords in a document:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'watermelon']
y_predicted = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'watermelon']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_predicted))
```

As in this case, the words are aligned against each other, I can calculate the F1 score for this.

However, what if my model doesn't know which order to place the words in? For example, if I place them like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'watermelon']
y_predicted = ['orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'watermelon', 'mango']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_predicted))
```

I will get a `zero` score for all the keywords even though the model correctly determined 3 out of 5.

Do you know if there's an adjustment I can do to this metric in `sklearn` so that it doesn't care about the order of items matched (and their number for that matter as well)?

Or maybe there's another metrics I could use?

Comment: I don't think the second case exists - the true and predicted labels should always match in order. So, your second block of code corresponds to a model which has predicted all labels incorrectly.

Comment: @KRKirov it does exist. if you abstract from this particular implementation `precision` calculates how precise your predictions were (% of words in the predicted set that were also in the ground truth set), while `recall` calculates how much of the original ground truth you recovered (% of words in the ground truth set that were in your predicted set). so i'm just looking for that way of measuring precision/recall.

Comment: My first comment was on the order of true and predicted labels, not on the labels themselves or on precision and recall. Please read it again. Precision and recall are described here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html.

Comment: You can do it with pure python, here is simple example:
`precision = len([(i, j) for i,j in zip(y_predicted,y_true) if i==j]) / len(y_true)` and
`recall = len([i for i in y_predicted if i in y_true]) / len(y_true)`

Comment: That still only works if the words are aligned @bollence...